# Google Play Rejected My React Native App Because It Includes an SDK that is not there

Tags: react-native, google-play

Google Play rejected a recent version of my react native app. In their original message they mentioned:

> We detected user data transmitted off device that you have not disclosed in your app’s Data safety form as user data collected.
>
> We found an issue in the following area(s):
>
> SPLIT_BUNDLE 21: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Device Or Other IDs Data Type - Device Or Other IDs (some common examples may
> include Advertising ID, Android ID, IMEI, BSSID, MAC address)

When I asked for more information, they replied with:

> For example, your app includes **segment_analytics** SDK or an SDK that
> one of your libraries depends on, which collects personal or sensitive
> data that includes but may not be limited to identifiers.

This is unsettling because I am not using segment analytics and am not sending any identifier off-device on purpose. I have literally tried to

```
grep -rn 'segment_analytics' .
```

all my local app directory and have found no trace of `segment_analytics`. I don't want to change the data safety section of my app because I am not collecting/using device identifiers. Besides, if any of the SDKs I use are using such identifiers, I would like to know.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72584447/com-segment-analytics-androidanalytics-error-while-submitting-my-app-to-google) mentions expo but I am not using expo and I am building on my machine so I assume my machine has all the files needed for the build. I followed the steps in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73163150/1582032) and found nothing related to analytics in the app.

Is there any other way that my app could be using other SDKs? How would I find out? Is it possible that this is just an error from Google Play Support?